# MongoDB: how to add the specific fields from one query with alias to result of another query using Java (with or without Spring)?

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, nosql

If we have collection "orders"

```
{"_id":"1",
 "currency": "USD"//...
}
```

And collection "order_items"

```
{"_id":"1",
 "order":"1",
 "product":"p1",
 "totalItemAmount": 25
},
 {"_id":"2",
 "order":"1",
 "product":"p2",
 "totalItemAmount": 50
}
```

How to get such result

```
[{
"orderId": "1",
"currency": "USD",
"products": ["p1", "p2"]
"totalOrderAmount": "75"
}]
```

using Java (with or without Spring)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve that using an aggregation like this:

```js
db.orders.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "order_items",
      "as": "items",
      "localField": "_id",
      "foreignField": "order"
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$items"
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$_id",
      "totalOrderAmount": {
        "$sum": "$items.totalItemAmount"
      },
      "products": {
        "$push": "$items.product"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "_id": 0,
      "orderId": "$_id",
      "currency": 1,
      "totalOrderAmount": {
        "$toString": "$totalOrderAmount"
      },
      "products": 1
    }
  }
])
```

I don't know which driver you're using in Java but it's not hard to adapt it to the language you're using